# Entity Framework POCO SaveChanges() on Update doesn't work?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, poco

I'm working with EF CTP 4, using POCO models, adding a new object and call SaveChanges() works but updating the object doesn't work. Here's the code for update:

```
public void UpdateContact(Contact contact)
        {
            var findContact = GetContact(contact.ContactID);
            findContact = contact;
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

public Contact GetContact(int contactId)
        {
            return GetAllContacts().SingleOrDefault(c => c.ContactID == contactId);
        }

public IQueryable<Contact> GetAllContacts()
        {
            return _context.Contacts;
        }
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem is that when you assign `findContact = contact` the `EntityState` does not get changed in the `ObjectStateManager` (so it's still set to `Unchanged`). Therefore, no `Update` SQL statement gets generated for the entity. You have several options to do the update:

**Option 1:** Populate `findContact` field-by-field:

```
var findContact = GetContact(contact.ContactID);
findContact.FirstName = contact.FirstName;
findContact.LastName = contact.LastName;
...
_context.SaveChanges();
```

**Option 2:** Use the `ApplyCurrentValues` method:

```
var findContact = GetContact(contact.ContactID);
_context.ApplyCurrentValues("Contacts", contact);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

**Option 3:** Attach the updated entity and change the state in the `ObjectStateManager`. (Note: this will not make a roundtrip to the database for fetching the existing contact).

```
_context.AttachTo("Contacts", contact);
var contactEntry = Context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(contact);
contactEntry.ChangeState(EntityState.Modified);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Hi Yakimych, with **Option 1**, can I use AutoMapper to map between findContact and contact, instead of mapping each property? Thanks.

Comment: @Saxman - Even though `AutoMapper` is normally used to map between objects of different types, you can try using the same type on both sides of the mapping. I haven't used it myself, but you could give it a go. And please post an update after you solve the problem - it might be useful for future reference.

Comment: For some reason I can't call method **ApplyCurrentValues()** with my context, so option 2 ruled out. I did not try option 3. AutoMapper didn't work in this situation, I have to manually set the properties of findContact equals to contact. Thanks!