# EF Context.SaveChanges() does nothing

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
try 
{
    Context.SaveChanges();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
     Log(e);
}
finally
{
    Log("Complete");
}
```

When Context.SaveChanges() is called it silently fails. An exception is not thrown and the finally clause is never hit. Has anyone run into this before?

Comment: Does the context have any changes?  What is the return value of `SaveChanges`?

Comment: Does that matter? If there are no changes, `SaveChanges` returns normally, and the `finally` clause would get hit. (Actually, asking for the return value of `SaveChanges` is good; if a return value can be found, it returns normally.) What I'd like to know is how you know the `finally` clause doesn't get hit. Did you run this in a debugger, setting a breakpoint on the call to `SaveChanges`, and then step through? Also, what does `Log` look like?

Comment: yes there are a lot of changes that occur before I call SaveChanges. I get a record from the database, change quite a few values and add a record to a table that has a foreign key relation to the original entity then call SaveChanges. I have had this inside and outside a transaction scope. I have also removed the line adding the the table with the foreign key relation to see if that had anything to do with it and I still get the same.

Comment: @hvd yes I put breakpoints in the catch and the finally

Comment: Check out the following [link][1]. Does this help?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075107/entity-framework-poco-savechanges-on-update-doesnt-work

Comment: For me SaveChanges does nothing, doesn't throw an exception and ends the function scope immediately. Execution continues as if that function had returned.

Comment: var rowsAffected= Context.SaveChanges();can you change this and see what you get in rowsAffected

Comment: nothing. execution stopped before .SaveChanges() finished

Comment: What about putting `throw;` to your catch.

Comment: does nothing.. the catch block doesn't get hit at all

Comment: Hard to tell just looking at the code you have but it seems like you might have something running asynchronously within the SaveChanges method.  I've seen crazy behavior before when not waiting on SQL to finish before exiting the method and things go out of scope.

Comment: what you mean by nothing.Null or zero

Comment: Codelgnoto, Actually I lied. when I went to look at what was returned it stops execution of the running thread. The application itself continues working but the thread stops.

Comment: As an update that. I made the thread its own application and ran it. The application just crashes

Comment: does the output window show any error messages when it crashes

Comment: And what does "crashes" mean? If somehow `SaveChanges` gets into an infinite loop, as a random example, I wouldn't call it a crash, but others might.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end my problem was my POCO file didn't match the Database :(
I wonder why though there was no exception thrown...

Answer (score 0):

There should be some problem with your Log method.

Does it have proper function overloading.

Comment: Never hits the logging calls. Execution stops on SaveChanges.